# Restructuring Pandas Dataframe to transpose data into two columns of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, transpose

Python beginner here. I have a Panda Dataframe that I would like to in lack of a better term, to transpose into rows of data for each single item in my second column. My current dataframe looks like this:

```
    SECTION   VALUES
0   A1        ['RC47']
1   A2        ['AC_100''AC_101''AC_102''AC_103''AC_104''AC105''AC_106''AC_107']
2   A3        ['RT1''RT2''RT3']
3   A4        ['800''801''802''803''804''805''1000''1001']
4   B3T2      ['RC50''RC50''RC50''RC50']
5   BR40      ['RC44']
6   T1        ['941.2''943.4''945.3''960.2']
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
SECTION   VALUES
A1        13_200
A1        23_10
A1        200_300
A1        200_10
A2        AC_100
A2        AC_101
A2        AC_103
A3        AC_104
etc ...
```

The portion of my code that I'm having trouble with setting up a proper syntax and output dataframe with is below:

```
#print(percentages)

list_of_keys = []
list_of_values = []
for key,val in percentages.items():
    list_of_keys.append(key)
    list_of_values.append(val)

#print(list_of_keys)
#print(list_of_values)

head =['SECTION','VALUES']
newdf = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list_of_keys, list_of_values)), columns=head)
print(newdf)
out = (newdf.assign(VALUES= newdf["VALUES"]
                   .replace(",", "','", regex=True).apply(literal_eval))
             .explode("VALUES"))#.reset_index(drop=True) uncomment to make a unique index
```

The error I receive is below:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: array(['RC47']
```

The error is on the line:

```
.replace(",", "','", regex=True).apply(literal_eval))
```

I'm having difficulty with handling the syntax of the second column 'VALUES'. The lists of data aren't delimited by anything aside from each value being inside apostrophes. I know typically this problem is handled by `DataFrame.transpose()` but the apostrophe formatting is giving me trouble. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the values you are creating is a list of list?

Answer (score 1):

One of the options would be a [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)/[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) :

```
from ast import literal_eval
​
out = (df.assign(VALUES= df["VALUES"]
                 .replace("''", "','", regex=True).apply(literal_eval))
           .explode("VALUES"))#.reset_index(drop=True) uncomment to make a unique index
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   SECTION   VALUES
0       A1   13_200
0       A1    23_10
0       A1  200_300
..     ...      ...
3       A4      805
3       A4     1000
3       A4     1001

[23 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: this is a pretty good solution. This doesn't seem to work where there is only one value for a section though.

Comment: I tried with single element lists and it works. Can you give an example and include it to your question ?

Comment: I'm receiving an error `ValueError: malformed node or string: array(['RC47'], dtype=object)` Which is means it's saying I can't pass lists / dictionary / tuples, etc. to the `ast.literal_eval ` but I'm passing a dataframe so I'm confused there. I have the same code you have above but with my dataset being slightly different. My error states me to the first array of section data which is just a single value in the value column.

Comment: *..with my dataset being slightly different.* Can you share a reproducible example that describe your dataset when throwing the error and include it to your question ?

Comment: I just updated my question with all that you mentioned above. I hope this helps, apologies.

Comment: No problem but I still can't reproduce the error (*even with the new example*). Can you make it with the `pd.DataFrame` constuctor ? You can do `print(df.to_dict("list"))`.

Comment: which portion of the code? Under the ```newdf = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list_of_keys, list_of_values)), columns=head)``` line?

Comment: How do we reproduce your data?

Comment: @KayvanShah I brought it in from a CSV and converted it to a dataframe as you can see in the question. section and values are two different columns